# Compatibility of Shared Library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have an API that 3rd parties use to create shared libraries which are dynamically linked into my application. These shared libraries declare public functions that return their implementation of a pure virtual class defined in the API. The application can then call the various virtual methods on this class to interface with the 3rd party code.

The problem I'm having is when I change the API and attempt to use an 'outdated' shared library (specifically changing the return type). The library is loaded fine (and some methods are called without problems), but  I get a segmentation fault when there is a mismatch in the function signature.

I understand why this is happening (and that the 'fix' is to get an updated shared library), however I was hoping that I could handle this error more gracefully in my application. **How can I check if a given shared library is compatible with the current version of the API** (so I can log a useful error)?

Comment: Add another pure base class where you ask which version they implement (also simply a constant you change in your header files each time you update your API will work pretty well for this). Something like PlugInDescriptor::GetApiVersion(). Of course you have to keep PlugInDescriptor signature fixed. Also a _plain_ exported C function will work well.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I had considered using version checking as you described, however as shared libraries already exist without this capability it's not ideal (indeed it's something that should have been implemented from the start). Also, changes to the API _should_ be minimal so this issue shouldn't be too prevalent in the future. 

Could you elaborate on how I could plain C functions to solve this? I currently use these in the shared libraries to return the virtual class used by the application.

Comment: An exported function as you're using to get classes. If GetProcAddress returns NULL then it's an older version...if it returns an address then you can call GetPlugInApiVersion() safely and check the version...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Ah I see it ties into the versioning. Sorry, I thought you meant that as an alternative, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I check if a given shared library is compatible with the current version of the API

There are three "standard" solutions:

- Have a function in the library which returns a version string, or better yet a `(major, minor, patchlevel)` tuple. Compare the returned result with what the application needs.
- Have the new version of the library have a different *external* version: `libfoo.so.1`, `libfoo.so.2`, etc. Your application will fail to run if it can't find the library it needs. Read about external library versioning [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E26506/chapter5-5.html).
- On Linux and other GLIBC platforms, an even better solution is to do what GLIBC does: use versioned symbols. This allows old application to continue using the new version of the library, and still get an old symbol, while new applications will get new symbol. A new application running with old library will fail to start with a "missing symbol@Version" error. Symbol versioning is described [here](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=33).

Answer (score 0):

> These shared libraries declare public functions that return their implementation of a pure virtual class defined in the API.

Which probably means your shared libraries have the following interface:

```
struct Lib
{
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

extern "C" Lib& getLib();
```

Here `getLib` is that *public function* you mentioned.

> How can I check if a given shared library is compatible with the current version of the API

Require a new version of a shared library to have a differently named *public function*.